# Extjs Combo Box value from php file

Tags: cakephp-1.3, extjs4

In my php file i write:

```
  function maintcond4() 
{
 $this->layout=null;
 $condition_list_value_list4= array("New","Excellent","good","Poor","Scrap");
 echo '{maint_condition4:'.json_encode($condition_list_value_list4).'}';
}
```

In my js file i write:

```
       Ext.define('User4', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name: 'maint_condition4', type: 'string'}
                ]
        });
```

and

```
      { header: "Maint_condition4", dataIndex: "maint_condition4", flex: 1,
                    editor:
                    {
                        xtype : 'combobox',
                        editable : false,   
                        queryMode: 'remote',
                        displayField: 'maint_condition4', 
                        valueField: 'maint_condition4',
                        emptyText: "Select...",
                        loadingText: "Loading...",
                        allowBlank: false,
                        store :Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                            autoLoad: true,
                            fields: [ 'maint_condition4' ],
                            proxy: {
                                type: 'ajax',
                                extraParams: {typeName : 'maint_condition4'},
                                url :r+'tbl_maintenance_records/maintcond4',
                                reader: {
                                    type: 'json',
                                    root : 'maint_condition4'
                                }
                            }                       
                        }),
                        name : 'maint_condition4'
                        }
                }
```

My combox displayfields are not showing.i think in php file array popullation may be wrong or in js file store section doesnot get display field name.please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

First of all add to your store declaration `model: 'User4'`. Second, after page is loaded add console.log(combobox.store) to debug what you actually have in the store. If you don't have anything - trace calls to your PHP script and check whether its result is parsed properly.